# Error when attempting to full join of two arrow tables in R

Tags: r, join, apache-arrow

I reached out to the package developers on this but wanted to see if anyone else had encountered the same issue.

I'm having a problem where I'm trying to use `full_join()` on two tables (subset from the same data but filtered and operated on and appended to save memory), but it keeps throwing the following error:

```
Error: NotImplemented: Function 'coalesce' has no kernel matching input types (numeric(0)
attr(,"class")
[1] NA, numeric(0)
attr(,"class")
```

Specifically, it looks something like the following:

```
library(arrow)
library(tidyverse)
library(fastDummies)

  temp <- open_csv_dataset(sources = cohort_csvs) %>% compute()
  
  Subs <- data.frame(temp %>% distinct(key) %>% collect())
  
  for (Subnum in 1:dim(Subs)[1]) {
    out <-
      data.frame(temp %>% filter(key == Subs[Subnum, ]) %>% collect())
      out[is.na(out)] <- 'NA'
      out$tags <- 'NA'
      out <-
        dummy_cols(
          out,
          select_columns = "terms",
          remove_selected_columns = FALSE,
          omit_colname_prefix = TRUE
        )
      out <-
        dummy_cols(
          out,
          select_columns = "tags",
          remove_selected_columns = FALSE,
          omit_colname_prefix = TRUE
        )
      if (Subnum == 1){
        Out_table <- arrow_table(out)
      } else {
        Out_table <-Out_table %>% full_join(out)
        }
```

However, when it reaches past the first part of the loop to the full join, it throws the error regardless of the call used to make the `full_join()`:

```
Out_table %>% full_join(out)
Error: NotImplemented: Function 'coalesce' has no kernel matching input types (numeric(0)
attr(,"class")
[1] NA, numeric(0)
attr(,"class")
[1] NA)

full_join(Out_table,arrow_table(out))
Error: NotImplemented: Function 'coalesce' has no kernel matching input types (numeric(0)
attr(,"class")
[1] NA, numeric(0)
attr(,"class")
[1] NA)

full_join(Out_table,out)
Error: NotImplemented: Function 'coalesce' has no kernel matching input types (numeric(0)
attr(,"class")
[1] NA, numeric(0)
attr(,"class")
[1] NA)
```

It will **not** however, throw any error or display issues with left, right, inner, semi, or anti join.

I kind of need all columns to be retained during the joining, even if as NAs.

Any idea what might be causing the issue or how to get around it?

Thanks in advance!

Version info:

- OS: NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server" VERSION="7.9 (Maipo)"

R Version:

- R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23) -- "Funny-Looking Kid"

RStudio Version:

- RStudio Server 2022.07.0 Build 548

Session Info:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/libopenblasp-r0.3.3.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices datasets  utils     methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] lubridate_1.9.0   timechange_0.1.1  rmarkdown_2.18    here_1.0.1        fastDummies_1.7.3 arrow_12.0.1.1   
 [7] data.table_1.14.6 toolbox_0.1.0     janitor_2.2.0     forcats_0.5.2     stringr_1.4.1     dplyr_1.0.10     
[13] purrr_0.3.5       readr_2.1.3       tidyr_1.2.1       tibble_3.1.8      ggplot2_3.4.0     tidyverse_1.3.2  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.4.4          vroom_1.6.0         bit64_4.0.5         jsonlite_1.8.3      viridisLite_0.4.1   splines_4.2.1      
 [7] modelr_0.1.10       assertthat_0.2.1    pander_0.6.5        renv_0.16.0         googlesheets4_1.0.1 cellranger_1.1.0   
[13] yaml_2.3.6          pillar_1.8.1        backports_1.4.1     lattice_0.20-45     glue_1.6.2          digest_0.6.30      
[19] rvest_1.0.3         snakecase_0.11.1    colorspace_2.0-3    htmltools_0.5.5     Matrix_1.5-3        survey_4.1-1       
[25] pkgconfig_2.0.3     broom_1.0.1         haven_2.5.1         scales_1.2.1        webshot_0.5.4       svglite_2.1.0      
[31] tzdb_0.3.0          googledrive_2.0.0   generics_0.1.3      tictoc_1.1          ellipsis_0.3.2      DT_0.26            
[37] withr_2.5.0         cli_3.4.1           survival_3.3-1      magrittr_2.0.3      crayon_1.5.2        readxl_1.4.1       
[43] evaluate_0.18       fs_1.5.2            fansi_1.0.3         xml2_1.3.3          tableone_0.13.2     tools_4.2.1        
[49] mitools_2.4         hms_1.1.2           gargle_1.2.1        lifecycle_1.0.3     munsell_0.5.0       reprex_2.0.2       
[55] kableExtra_1.3.4    compiler_4.2.1      systemfonts_1.0.4   rlang_1.1.2         grid_4.2.1          rstudioapi_0.14    
[61] htmlwidgets_1.6.0   gtable_0.3.1        DBI_1.1.3           R6_2.5.1            knitr_1.41          bit_4.0.5          
[67] fastmap_1.1.0       utf8_1.2.2          rprojroot_2.0.3     stringi_1.7.8       parallel_4.2.1      Rcpp_1.0.9         
[73] vctrs_0.6.4         dbplyr_2.2.1        tidyselect_1.2.0    xfun_0.35
```

I attempted to re-create an example, but this one actually works.
Was hoping it might be useful in identifying the underlying issue:

```
df <- arrow_table(data.frame (ID  = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "ID5", "ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "ID5", "ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "ID5", "ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "ID5", "ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "ID5"),
                  String = c("Value_A", "Value_B", "Value_C", "Value_D", "Value_E", "Value_F", "Value_G", "Value_H", "Value_I", "Value_J", "Value_A", "Value_C", "Value_C", "Value_C", "Value_E", "Value_G", "Value_G", "Value_H", "Value_I", "Value_J", "Value_K", "Value_L", "Value_M", "Value_N", "Value_N")
                  ))
                  
UniqueIDs <- data.frame(df %>% distinct(ID) %>% collect())
                  
  for (IDcall in 1:dim(df %>% distinct(ID) %>% collect())[1]) {
    out <-
      data.frame(df %>% filter(ID == UniqueIDs[IDcall,]) %>% collect())
      out <-
        dummy_cols(
          out,
          select_columns = "String",
          remove_selected_columns = FALSE,
          omit_colname_prefix = TRUE
        )
      if (IDcall == 1){
        Dummytable <- arrow_table(out)
      } else {
        Dummytable <- Dummytable %>% full_join(out)
        }
      }
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this question reproducible? I don't know how to cause that error.

Comment: I attempted to do so making my own dataframes and then converting them to tables, but it worked when I did that (possibly *because* I did that rather than using the raw data).

Comment: Are you using the dplyr function `coalesce` in any of your code?

Comment: dummy_cols is from `fastDummies` presumably?

Comment: @JonSpring, I am not using `coalesce`, but on the full join I made that *does* work, it is being invoked to join the tables (e.g. Value_N: int32 (coalesce(Value_N.x, Value_N.y)))
And yes, `dummy_cols` is from `fastDummies`.

Comment: @TDeramus could you please link where you've reached out to the package developers so we can keep the streams synchronized?

Comment: @amoeba Of course.
https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/39038